# Informatica records scenario

Tags: informatica

I have huge no of records from source. I have to load first 1000 records into first target, second 1000 records into second target, third 1000 records into third target, fourth 1000 records into first target, fifth 1000 records into second target, next thousand records into third target and so on...can any one give me solution for this...I was able to load 3000 records into 3 different targets but unable to load 3001-4000 records into first target and 4001-5000 records into second target and so on...

Comment: Pls use 1. exp to calculate `flag = iif (MOD(count,1000)=0 then count/1000,-1) ` 2. Use transaction control to create multiple files based on flag. 3. you need to add a filename n target and control the filename using expression.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this...

1. Use a sequence generator to tag each row with a row number
2. Create a calculated field that gives a value of 1, 2 or 3 based on the sequence value i.e using the logic you outlined in your question
3. Use a router transformation to direct each row to the appropriate target based on the calculated field

Comment: I already tried this and this logic doesn't resolve the problem.Because we can't load 1-1000 records into first target, 1001-2000 records into second target, 2001-3000 records into third target and next thousand records into first target again..

Comment: router will not work in dynamic scenario. you need transaction control and a flag that will control count of rows.

Comment: @infdev Please can you explain why this logic doesn't resolve your problem - what have I misunderstood about your requirements? If you have logic that flags which target each record should be written to and a router that directs the records to the appropriate target then what am i missing? Thanks